# SQL Server 2008 Express SSRS: export to CSV

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-express, ssrs-2008

Do Reporting Services in SQL Server 2008 support export to CSV? I only see Excel/Word/PDF in the dropdown list on in the SSRS localhost server when previewing report. I found in internet that SSRS 2008 seems to support CSV but I don't see it; is it Express limitation? I haven't found any notes about this limitation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSV export is not supported in the Express edition:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281020.aspx

The following list describes the features that are documented in SQL Server Books Online, but cannot be used in this edition:

- Scheduled report processing, caching,
  snapshots, subscriptions, and
  delivery are not supported.
- Analysis Services, Oracle, XML, SAP,
  SQL Server Integration Services
  (SSIS), OLE DB, and ODBC data sources
  are not supported.
- Remote data sources are not
  supported. Reports that are hosted in
  a SQL Server Express report server
  must retrieve SQL Server relational
  data from a local SQL Server Express
  Database Engine instance.
- Ad hoc reporting through semantic
  models and Report Builder is not
  supported.
- TIFF (Image), XML, and **CSV rendering
  extensions** are not supported.
- The Reporting Services API extensible
  platform for delivery, data
  processing, rendering, and security
  is not supported.
- Custom authentication extensions and
  custom role assignments are not
  supported. You must map existing
  Windows domain user and group
  accounts to predefined role
  definitions.
- Custom report items are not
  supported.
- Managing a long-running report
  process is not supported.
  Specifically, you cannot use the
  Manage Jobs feature in Report Manager
  to stop report processing.
- Scale-out deployment is not
  supported.
- SharePoint integrated mode is not
  supported.
- Report Builder 2.0 is not supported.
  Report Builder 2.0 can connect to a
  SQL Server Express database on the
  local computer or on a remote report
  server.

Comment: Thanks (sigh). I didn't find this using Google.