# How to enable the export to 'csv' in Report Server

Tags: csv, reporting-services, export-to-csv, ssrs-2012

I am trying to export to CSV on reporting services however the option is not there.  I have the option the export on the local machine but not reporting services.

Local: [image]

Reporting Services: [image]

I am using VS Community 2013:

[image]

From C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS12.SQLEXPRESS\Reporting Services\ReportServer. I have gone into the rereportserver.config file and added after the "Render" tag.

```
<Extension Name="CSV"    Type="Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.DataRenderer.CsvReport,Microsoft.ReportingServices.DataRendering">
<OverrideNames>
<Name Language="en-US">CSV</Name>
</OverrideNames>
<Configuration>
<DeviceInfo>
<FieldDelimiter>&#9;</FieldDelimiter>
<UseFormattedValues>False</UseFormattedValues>
<NoHeader>False</NoHeader>
<FileExtension>csv</FileExtension>
</DeviceInfo>
</Configuration>
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208743/sql-server-2008-express-ssrs-export-to-csv

Comment: Check server log, there may be issues when loading assembly with rendering extension.

Comment: Richard looks like you are correct.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208743/sql-server-2008-express-ssrs-export-to-csv